# Summernote editor not show any content on django admin page

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-serializer, summernote

I'm using summernote package in my django project. However, the editor is not showing any content. The `body = TextField()` is completely blank (the whole space is white) in the admin page as shown in the attached file.

```
admin.py

class postAdmin(SummernoteModelAdmin):
    summernote_fields = '__all__'

admin.site.register(post, postAdmin)
```

settings.py

```
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = "SAMEORIGIN"
```

models.py

```
class post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    body = models.TextField()
    ...
```

serializers.py

```
class post_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = post
        fields = '__all__'
        lookup_field = 'slug'
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('summernote/',include('django_summernote.urls')),
    ...
]
```

[image]

I saw similar question online but none of the approaches I saw worked for me. How do I make the textfield in the screenshot editatble? I'm not using bootstrap or css because I'm creating an api that will be consumed by a frontend react app.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved with:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/staticfiles/

Answer (score -1):

What I didn't know is that I need to turn on internet connection before summernote will load if my internet connection is turned off it doesn't load. So if you encounter similar issue and your code seems accurate, the fix might just be to turn on your internet connection